# Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. ---- already used thunk

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I already used thunk middlewares but still getting errors why is that? ------- What am I missing?
[image]

App.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts())
  }, [dispatch])
```

Actions file:

```
import * as api from "../api/index"

export const getPosts = async dispatch => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchPosts()
        dispatch({ type: "GET_ALL", payload: data })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

Reducers File:

```
export const reducers = (posts = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_ALL":
            return action.payload

        default:
            return posts
    }
}
```

Store File:

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reducers } from "../reducers/index"
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';


const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
export default store
```

Comment: @Andy, please help

Comment: @Vilius Paulauskas, please help

Comment: Your thunk is not really a thunk, it's supposed to be a function that returns a function (notice the two `=>` they normally have). Your function returns a promise.

Comment: @imotgl
Can you please inform, What should I write here?

Comment: oh Thanks a lot @imotgl, Now it worked, I just used `const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(() => thunk)))`, and it totally fine now

Comment: @RiyadHossain that might make the error disappear but is 100% wrong - it will probably make your app crash in weird ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a thunk there, not a thunk action creator.

So either you do

```
dispatch(getPosts)
```

or you do

```
export const getPosts = () => async dispatch => {
```

That said, you are writing a very outdated style of Redux here - in modern Redux (since 2019) you don't write swich...case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable reducer logic or action creators by hand.
You also should not use `createStore` (which by now is deprecated), `compose` or `applyMiddleware`.

Please read [Why Redux Toolkit is How To Use Redux Today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today). Modern Redux is about 1/4 of the code.

You are probably following a very outdated tutorial. I'd recommend you follow the [official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @phry. I really appreciate your effort and support.